# Loop nested JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json structure like this

```
[
  {
    “id” : 1,
    “user_id” : 1,
    “location” :  {
       “long” : 34.2489234,
       “lat” : -117.234234,
    },
    “active” : 1
  },   {
    “id” : 2,
    “user_id” : 2,
    “location” :  {
       “long” : 34.245234234,
       “lat” : -116.23786834,
    },
    “active” : 1
  },   {
    “id” : 3,
    “user_id” : 3,
    “location” :  {
       “long” : 34.245634234,
       “lat” : -114.237787834,
    },
    “active” : 0
   }
]
```

how can i loop through the data so i would only get the location "long" and "lat"?

Comment: You can't use curly quotes in JSON.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: The JSON data above has a comma after the lat value. This will break some JSON parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Start by decoding the json-string:

```
$data = json_decode($the_json_string);
```

This will give you a php-array with objects which you can loop through like usual:

```
foreach($data as $obj) {
    echo $obj->location->long;
    echo $obj->location->lat;
}
```

Comment: i already tried that but it is only returning the first value? never gets through the next record.

Comment: Then show what you have done... I can't debug your code if I don't get to see it. What I wrote does work..   however.. you have errors in your JSON-string... you need to remove the comma after the `"lat"` parameters (in PHP.arrays this is allowed but not in JSON) and replace the curly quotes with standard `"`

Comment: oh, i just manually typewritten those json string from my multiple nested json data - my apologies. so basically it is a wp_remote_get request and my for loop script is similar to yours but it is just displaying 1 record and cant get throug next. any workaround?

Comment: Similar isn't the same..  update your question with what you have tried... you haven't given us anything to go with here...  the json isn't a copy of the actuall json-string, you haven't shown the code you tried... we're not psycics...

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = json_decode($json,true);

    foreach ($data as $obj ){
      echo $obj['location']['long'];


      echo $obj ['locaion']['len'];
}
```

I hope this will work